# Tub overflow elbow standard screw pattern; 2 or 1 screw?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, drain, bathtub

Is there a standard screw for tub overflow elbows?  Or most popular?  I am installing a new tub and looking for a overflow elbow with a screw pattern that will lend itself to a stylish overflow now, and replacement parts for when it gets rusty and grimy down the road.

I've included a picture of a one-screw overflow and two-screw that I have available to me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Get the 2 hole one; it'll work for those, and single screw overflows almost always come with a bridging plate.

Comment: If you do not want to decide which faucet set to buy until later. I would go with Aloysius on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use whichever fits the hole in the tub better. Note that the 2 hole elbow is a bit larger and may cover better.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the only standard is what your bath faucet, knob, overflow & drain (maybe showerhead too, but who buys those they're always the worst clean out the warehouse afterthoughts) ensemble is. The manufacturer of whatever you buy should include its own overflow & drain. If you already have it & it doesn't have these for some reason, then either is fine & just depends on what's available at the store.